# Efficient way to map properties from multiple objects to single object with same property names

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the current way in how i'm doing it now. Wondering if there is a better way as the actual use case is about 150 lines of this. Preferably with a map function or something along those lines.

```ts
this.component = {
  item1: 0,
  item2: 2
}

this.otherComponent = {
  item3: 0,
  item4: 2
}
        
this.form = {
  item1: this.component.item1,
  item2: this.component.item2,
  item3: this.otherComponent.item3,
  item4: this.otherComponent.item4,
}
```

Comment: "*the actual use case is about 150 lines of this*" - with more items? With more components? Do you actually have an array of them (or could easily put them into one)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably looking to use `Object.assign`:

```
this.form = Object.assign({}, this.component, this.otherComponent);
```

or object spread syntax:

```
this.form = {...this.component, ...this.otherComponent};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course!

You can use the [(...)Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
this.component = {
  item1: 0,
  item2: 2
}

this.otherComponent = {
  item3: 0,
  item4: 2
}
        
this.form = { ...this.component, ...this.otherComponent }
```

Example:

```js
let component = {
  item1: 0,
  item2: 2
}

let otherComponent = {
  item3: 0,
  item4: 2
}

let form = {...component, ...otherComponent}
      
console.log(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey What you can do is spread these objects out:

```
const a = {
  item1: 0,
  item2: 2
}

const b = {
  item3: 0,
  item4: 2
}
        
const result = {
 ...a,
 ...b
}
```

This will give desired results